# How would you call a non-abstract method of a abstract class?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, cglib

This Question answers on handling abstract method types; but how to proxy the non-abstract portion of the methods?
[Implementing abstract methods at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425219/implementing-abstract-methods-at-runtime)

How can I execute the following to call `sayHello()`?

package cglibtest;

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor;
import net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy;

public class CGLibTest
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        MyAbstract instance = (MyAbstract)Enhancer.create(MyAbstract.class, new MyInterceptor(42));
        System.out.println("Value from instance: " + instance.valueMethod());
        System.out.println("Value from instance: " + instance.sayHello());
    }

    public static class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor
    {
        private final Object constantValue;

        public MyInterceptor(Object constantValue)
        {
            this.constantValue = constantValue;
        }

        @Override
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args,
                MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable
        {
            if ("valueMethod".equals(method.getName()))
                return(constantValue);
            else
                return(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class MyAbstract
    {
        public abstract int valueMethod();
         public String sayHello() { return "Hello" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone asked the same question as you. I Google'd it up and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722407/how-to-call-abstract-class-method-in-java) as the first
result. Check the answer there and your problem would be solved. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interceptor you have created does already override all methods, regardless of being `abstract` or not. What you seem to have missed is how to invoke the original method that you have overridden:

```
public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args,
        MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable
{
    if ("valueMethod".equals(method.getName()))
        return constantValue;
    else if("sayHello".equals(method.getName())) {
        System.out.println("before original sayHello()");
        // equivalent of saying super.sayHello() inside subclass
        Object result=proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
        System.out.println("after original sayHello()");
        return result;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: if I happen to have multiple abstract classes any ideas how may I forward them ?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are asking. In Java you can only extend from one `abstract` class. But you can implement multiple interfaces; cglib reflects that by providing an alternative `Enhancer.create` method accepting an array of interface `Class`es. But you can create different proxies for different `abstract` classes using only one interceptor implementation; in this case, as far as I understood, the `MethodProxy` which get passed to your `intercept` method will always be suitable to the currently invoked method. But of course, you can always implement multiple different interceptors.